# Excel Inventory Tracking (Clearing old inputs but keep that value)

Tags: excel, inventory-management

So I am intern and I have been tasked to do up a new inventory system on excel. I am not particularly good at excel so I sourced a inventory template online and just made minor adjustments.

My current issue is that I have 2 sheets. An input sheet that allows new entries whenever a raw material is added to our warehouse or if a raw material is used we can subtract from the total. The second sheet is the inventory sheet that displays the current amount of all the raw materials.

So the process flow is essentially:

1. Operator uses a raw material and enters the amount used in the input sheet. The formula used for all cells

For inputs (usage is the same, just different cell for BXX and CXX)
=IF(BXX="","",SUMIFS(Inputs!E$8:E$1000,Inputs!D$8:D$1000,CXX))

2. Inventory sheet automatically tracks the amount used/added and with a sum function.

However, it is planned to do a clean up of the inputs sheet on a yearly basis, so all old inputs that do not require tracking will be deleted. Obviously this would affect the inventory sheet as the quantity will be affected due to the dependency of the formula. Is there any simple way(without vba) to adjust the inventory formula such that if old entries are deleted, the value is not affected.

[This is how the inventory sheet looks like with the raw material input formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS9Cc.png)

[This is how the inventory sheet formula for total amount available looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehL2r.png)

Is there a way to edit the inventory sheet formula for total amount available ignore entries that have been deleted to keep the value intact?

Comment: use CSV. it's open source and compatible with excel.

Comment: After deleting entries you need to adjust formulas.

Comment: @Joshua How do I go about using CSV for this issue?

Comment: Hard to advise if you don't post the "before" csv and the "expected" csv

Comment: Edited 2 pictures if it might help?